# cabal install accelerate fails

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, accelerate

The error is :

```
mtl-2.2.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
primitive-0.6.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
text-1.2.2.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
unordered-containers-0.2.7.1 depends on text-1.2.2.1 which failed to install.
vector-0.11.0.0 depends on primitive-0.6.1.0 which failed to install.
```

running on ubuntu 14.04 cabal version 1.22.5.0 and ghc 8.0.1.

initially i had the haskell-platform installed but then i was unable to use the accelerate-cuda package because, it is not updated for cuda 7. So i tried to update ghc and cabal which i seem to have managed to do, but not sure where to go from here. Do i need to upgrade my OS to ubuntu 16.04? Would really love to get this working...

Answer (score 1):

it turned out that I just needed to

```
  $ ~ rm -rf .cabal
  $ cabal install accelerate
```